# Seleccionar segunda columna de un datalist

Tags: html5, lista

Tengo un `datalist` que alimento dinámicamente y voy añadiéndolo al elemento `datalist`.

```
objJson = JSON.parse(data);
$.each(objJson, function (i, item) {
    $('#entidadesLst').append("<option  value= " + objJson[i].id + " >" + " " + objJson[i].name + "</option>");
});
```

Me gustaría que al seleccionar un elemento de mi datalist, fuera `objJson[i].name` el que se vea en el campo  y no `objJson[i].id`. Quiero que se vea la segunda columna y no la primera. Cuando hablo de que se "vea en el campo" me refiero al `input` que usas para escribir, el `input` del `datalist`.

Comment: en cual campo?, al seleccionar una opción que debería ocurrir? el código que envías funciona correctamente? deberías formular mejor tu pregunta .

Comment: Andress, usted debería abrir un poco mas la mente, si tiene un select o en mi caso un datalist y selecciono un campo, me gustaria que se vieran la segunda columna de mi código. Creo que no es tan dificil

Comment: uuuh Que pedante... suerte.!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes intentar esto:

```
objJson = JSON.parse(data);

$.each(objJson, function (i, item) {

  $('#entidadesLst').append($("<option>").attr('value', objJson[i].name).attr("data-id",objJson[i].name));

});
```

Suponiendo que la el **json** llenó el **datalist**:

```js
$("#inputEntidadesLst").on('input', function () {
  var name = $(this).val();
  var id;
  
  if($('#entidadesLst option').filter(function(){
    if($(this).val() === name){
      id = $(this).attr("data-id");
      return $(this).attr("data-id");      
    }
  }).length) {
    $(this).val(name+" "+id);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="inputEntidadesLst" list="entidadesLst">
<datalist id="entidadesLst">
  <option value="David" data-id="1">
  <option value="Carolina" data-id="2">
  <option value="Freddy" data-id="3">
</datalist>
```

Como verás creo un evento `input` al campo donde tipeas el nombre, en dicho evento obtengo el valor tipeado y lo comparo con los **options** del **datalist**, si el nombre coincide con el que estoy tipeando obtengo el atributo `data-id` donde almaceno el id y al final seteo el valor del campo donde tipeao inicial mente mostrandote el nombre y el id juntos, tu puedes cambiar el orden puede colocar el nombre como `data-name` y el **id** como **value** y funcionará igual, espero te sirva. Es un ejemplo de como obtener seudos atributos de una `datalist`.

Comment: gracias por el esfuerzo David, pero al seleccionar el elemento, sigue mostrandome el campo id en el input en vez de mostrar el campo name

Comment: por alguna razón, no me muestra el id que corresponde al elemento name, además , me interesa que se vea la columna id. Gracias

Comment: Modifique mi respuesta

Answer (score 1):

```
objJson = JSON.parse(data);
$.each(objJson, function (i, item) {
  $('#entidadesLst').append($("<option>").attr('value', item.name));
  $('#entidadesLst').attr("value-id", item.id);//Se agrega id como metadata para poder acceder despues a é
  console.log($('#entidadesLst').attr("value-id"));//Mostraría el id del item
});
```

Comment: por favor explica tu código, las respuestas que son solo líneas de código sin explicación se consideran de baja calidad

Comment: Por favor no menosprecie la respuesta sólo porque no se explique las líneas de código. Muchas personas no necesitan que se les explique línea por línea.

Comment: estas en una comunidad donde mucha gente y no solo el OP la va a revisar y si debes explicarla por que llegará gente con conocimientos y gente novata; nadie desprecia tu respuesta no se donde leiste eso, lo que se te pide es simple, explica el código que pusiste